# Create events that fires off a coroutine from another script

Tags: c#, events, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I'm making an event that does the failLevel stuff when it fires off. For that I have made a delegate

```
    public delegate Coroutine FailGame(IEnumerator function);
    public static event FailGame gameFailedEvent;
```

like so and I subscribed the appropriate function to it

```
void Start ()
    {
        gameFailedEvent += StartCoroutine;
    }
```

It works when it is called from the same script like so:

```
gameFailedEvent(WaitThenFailLevel());
```

when this WaitThenFailLevel() looks like this:

```
IEnumerator WaitThenFailLevel()
    {
        CharacterController2D.playerDied = true;
        if (CharacterController2D.animState != CharacterController2D.CharAnimStates.fall)
        {
            CharacterController2D.currentImageIndex = 0;
            CharacterController2D.animState = CharacterController2D.CharAnimStates.fall;
        }
        CharacterController2D.movementDisabled = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.2f);
        StartCoroutine(ScaleTime(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.2f));
    }
```

It works fine here. Now, I have another object that can kill the player (dangerous times I know) and I don't want to copy paste everything again, I just want it to fire off the static event made in the script above.

I DID try making the WaitThenFailGame function

```
public static
```

and make static all my other ienumerators but I got an error named "An object reference is required for non-static field..."
Hence I tried the event stuff.
All well and fine, but I can't call the event from the other script because I can't pass it the function from the script mentioned.
What to do now?

Comment: Have a look at this, that might help you: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/224700/adding-a-coroutine-to-an-event.html

Comment: Thanks for the help, but commanding coroutines through events within the SAME script works. The problem is that I want to use ANOTHER script's enumerators. I tried that helper function that calls the enum, but if I make it static, the intellisense won't even let me call my enums in it due to different accessibility.

Comment: It's hard to understand your problem with the current code you have. Why not update your question with the complete script names and code inside them, then maybe someone might be able to fix your error.

Comment: Thanks for the input. The whole script is way to long not to lose context here.
What I basically need is using coroutines through events. 
However, I think I managed without this, by adding another state to my enum. took a bit of workaround, but so is life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the example code:

**EventContainor.cs**

```
public class EventContainer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static event Action<string> OnGameFailedEvent;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.R))
        {
            // fire the game failed event when user press R.
            if(OnGameFailedEvent = null)
                OnGameFailedEvent("some value");
        }

    }
}
```

**Listener.cs**

```
public class Listener : MonoBehaviour
{

    void Awake()
    {
        EventContainer.OnGameFailedEvent += EventContainer_OnGameFailedEvent;
    }

    void EventContainer_OnGameFailedEvent (string value)
    {
        StartCoroutine(MyCoroutine(value));
    }

    IEnumerator MyCoroutine(string someParam)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);

        Debug.Log(someParam);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using UnityEngine;
public class ScriptA : MonoBehaviour
{
  public ScriptB anyName;


  void Update()
  {
    anyName.DoSomething();
  }
}
```

---

```
using UnityEngine;
public class ScriptB : MonoBehaviour
{
  public void DoSomething()
  {
     Debug.Log("Hi there");
  }
}
```

This is linking functions between scripts , Copied from [Here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/7555/how-do-i-call-a-function-in-another-gameobjects-sc.html), maybe coroutines are the same, Then you need to start the coroutine in `void Start() {}` , You may find [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/782957/how-to-start-coroutine-from-another-script.html) useful as well.